Efficient Clifford circuit simulation for composite dimensional qudits
I'm looking for a reference that states that Clifford circuits can also be efficiently simulated classically for qudits with composite dimension $d$.
It is folklore that this result is true for qubits ($d=2$ case) due to the Gottesman-Knill theorem.
This paper suugests that the same is true in odd prime dimensions.
Although I have the impression from the community that the same is true for any $d$, I cannot find references for these results.
Would anyone be so kind to:

verify that the same result is true for any $d$,
provide me a reference where this is proved or argued, if true.

